# Reassignment of let variable makes TypeScript not recognized dynamically added type

Tags: typescript

I have a variable `userBalances` that is an object holding several properties from the start. However one property will be assigned later on which is called `categories`.

The function in which this is happening requires to return `userBalances` to be returned with the `categories` property to it.

```
// ... stuff before here
userBalances = userBalances.map((token) => {
  return {
    ...props,
    categories: ['a', 'b'], 
  };
});

return userBalances  // <- TS linter saying that `categories` is missing
```

However the code above does not work as it says that `categories` is missing. When I amend the code to the following:

```
// ... stuff before here
return userBalances.map((token) => {
  return {
    ...props,
    categories: ['a', 'b'], 
  };
}); // fine!
```

It works just fine. I don't understand why that happens?

Edit:
User balances is declared earlier in that function like so:

```
// an API result with an array of objects having all properties apart from `categories`
let userBalances = results.filter(({ balance }) => balance.gt(0));
```

Comment: Please update the question to provide a [mre]. In particular, please show us how `userBalances` is declared, but also just generally something more complete and less conceptual. For instance, in the above `props` comes out of nowhere, and `token` isn't used anywhere. Those kinds of things make it hard to help you with your actual problem.

Comment: The update still doesn't show us the type of `userBalances`, it just introduces more unknowns in the question. Please see my edited comment above (sorry for pressing Enter too soon on that).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean you have something like this:

```typescript
let userBalances = [
    {a: 1},
    {a: 2},
    {a: 3},
];

userBalances = userBalances.map((balance) => {
    return {
        ...balance,
        b: balance.a * 2,
    };
});

console.log(userBalances[0].b); // <== Error: Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: number; }'.(2339)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBArgziBOAhAhsZA7AxiGEC8EA2gFARkQDeyAXBAIwC+ANKeVbQEzOtnsQDM3ALoBuYsVgIUaLDnzQ4SVBmwwAdAFtkABwAUugEbLZASnwA+SjwjxwUeOivlnENW6MzsLF+QO0PKiBqyBAAVBAc3uQMYgwmYsSYAPboMEmgasBJAOa6kkqeOIQADEJqBvEQAPRVEAA8eAQAovDwSfC0AApt2ghgAJ4QAOQGQxAAJkly6EmQIAAeAJYwkCkQA73DFBA0EOhQGgYIIhAMQ2q6HPz8AJwmQA)

The problem is that although you've added a new property to the elements in `userBalances`, the *type* of `userBalances` hasn't changed, it's still `{a: number}[]` (in the above). It does happen that objects to have extra properties at runtime that TypeScript doesn't know about.

It doesn't happen when you do the `return` version because (I'm guessing) you've allowed TypeScript to infer the return type from the `return` statement rather than providing a specific type on the function definition.

The usual thing would be to assign to a new variable instead, allowing TypeScript to infer its type (as with the `return`):

```typescript
const userBalances = [
    {a: 1},
    {a: 2},
    {a: 3},
];

const updatedBalances = userBalances.map((balance) => {
    return {
        ...balance,
        b: balance.a * 2,
    };
});

console.log(updatedBalances[0].b); // <== Works
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJwEIEMA26zERGAXhgG0AoGSmAb3QC4YBGAXwBoKraGAmNjyrjADMfALoBuMmVCRYcAA4ATdFESKM2XPiLwkaLDjwQAdAFt08gBSWARga0BKIgD4a-GMkRQ4yMG6oBMMbBdpp47IFUNgyhhojG6DAAVDDcEVTMkswOktLgECCY8ZggAOaWCsqq6vZGJAAMosY2OTAA9G0wADyExADqIMgA1hBAA)

---

In a comment you've asked:

> thanks, your answer looks like my problem. However I still don't get it entirely why TS cannot see that I am re-assigning with the new properties. I think you are trying to explain it to my via this statement:
>
> > It does happen that objects to have extra properties at runtime that TypeScript doesn't know about
>
> ...but could you elaborate a little bit more?

I don't think TypeScript *changes* the type of an existing variable when you assign it a new value. (I can't say that for certain, but I don't think I've encountered it doing that.) It will [*narrow*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the contextual type of a union-typed variable, but what you're looking for above is for TypeScript to change the type of `userBalances` to include a `b` property on the array elements, as the result of an assignment. TypeScript just doesn't do that as far as I'm aware.

You can directly *tell* the compiler that the type has changed if you like, via either a type guard of some kind (probably a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) function) or an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions). Here's an example of using an assertion function:

```typescript
function assertElementsHaveNumberProperty<OriginalElementType, NewPropertyName extends PropertyKey>(
    array: OriginalElementType[],
    newProperty: NewPropertyName,
): asserts array is (OriginalElementType & {[K in NewPropertyName]: number})[] {
    for (const element of array) {
        if (typeof (element as any)[newProperty] !== "number") {
            throw new Error(`assertHasBNow failed`);
        }
    }
}

let userBalances = [
    {a: 1},
    {a: 2},
    {a: 3},
];
// Here, the element type of `userBalances is `{a: number}`.

userBalances = userBalances.map((balance) => {
    return {
        ...balance,
        b: balance.a * 2,
    };
});

// Here, the element type of `userBalances is still `{a: number}`.

assertElementsHaveNumberProperty(userBalances, "b");

// Now the element type of `userBalances is `{a: number} & {b: number}`,
// which is the same as `{a: number, b: number}`.

console.log(userBalances[0].b); // <== Works
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoFEA2GAthmFKgBLIBuGAciEQEbYAKWcADtlAJ4A8AeSwwA5jDDJ8BYqSgAVXtwA0iOhgDu7Lj151kJRBgAeUUgBNUibdxy8A0hl4A+ABQAoRF5RYsyXgBciMJiElIyJGSK3ADaALrKnt5gmja6QepaHLZ8+iSJAJRBaJg4Vsi+-ogwVq4h4pLShJEKShiIAGSIAN4x9tVImWl2eRhxQWCMLFgAvgXxPUlewHBYiK4QCKhQRs1yiHDAPn68BYveF9VHrnzch+sYe2Qo5WCnMSlZOnZxiACEAF4AYgAESTZjYEFnbpLS4XKAACw4GkQn0QuF8q1cAAMSjwqKgAEJ0OAo4DIGCEczYgoAblhFxmsKZTPchB2IFKhKkyEgGCswJisO6yCCAEYZokLiKggAmSXC0WIADMCri9IA9BrEBRsBhVIj2o9ZM9bu17tjOdhufheRB+dUrNiZaiptgZtiAHTuK1YG12-ma7UAPQA-O4fVyeXyBYhff6Y56iMhOK5XExo-azgDnOdvFgMFAQFgkDC4V5PZWM7a+VLy0wgtWA57kIgAFSIWV1rwzelzenuLU6vUGhFGp47M0HI6WqM1+1WGqIbaU-CIZ1K8HTD3e+OZwODkPh9x4nAROSUGj0N1YYZ8Vx7+f81QgphQgdDkkow27E2TtrTuuj4BouToulu7qdD0DauhCszYokQ4aAiMAQAijqID+qAGO0aDruBN6qDBEHwbuc4gUGiBhhGmxgKgcCEJ6+BwKID7kTGMQAAxxJ6TB0ogQ78ECiAAOqrAA1qg7hAA)

I don't recommend doing that, though, because it's unusual (at least in my experience), but that kind of explicit statement telling the compiler that the type of `userBalances` has changed *is* possible. I'd recommend using a new variable with an inferred type instead. It's also less cumbersome (no need for an assertion function).

Comment: thanks, your answer looks like my problem. However I still don't get it entirely why TS cannot see that I am re-assigning with the new properties. I think you are trying to explain it to my via this statement:
`It does happen that objects to have extra properties at runtime that TypeScript doesn't know about`, but could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @supersize - I've updated the answer to expand on that. Happy coding!

Comment: Technically adding a property is narrowing, but TypeScript doesn't do that automatically the way it does with unions (see [ms/TS#46489](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46489) among lots of others), mostly because it would end up having to synthesize new object types all over the place and that would be expensive.

Comment: @jcalz - Thank you, I *thought* it was narrowing (as it creates a more specific type) but didn't want to use the term incorrectly.